# Probability Question about an urn model

Tags: probability

So I just wrote an exam about probability and there was the following Question.
Suppose there is an urn with 6 balls. 2 of them are blue, 2 black, 2 white.
We draft four times without laying the balls back. 
Whats the probability of drafting exactly 2 blue balls?

My Answer
We can calculate it via the hypergeometric formula:

So it's
$$ p = \frac{\binom{2}{2} \cdot \binom{4}{2}}{\binom{6}{4}} = \frac{2}{5} $$
Is this true or false ? 
another Idea of me would be $ p = 1/3$, beacuse each time we draw, we must draw more than 1 pairs of same balls.

PS please excuse my bad english

Comment: Since all others has verified you calculation and explained about that, I try to clarify your doubt in the latter part. While it is true that it is equally likely for each color to appear exactly 2 times (0/1 time is also equally likely), now you are drawing 4 balls which allow two pairs of balls with the same color to appear. So the probability for a particular color to appear twice is larger than 1/3. As said above, the probability is 2/5 for all 3 colors and the sum of them is larger than 1. You will need to use inclusion-exclusion principle to verify that the probability of union is = 1.

Comment: ah i understand, thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is $$\frac{2}{5}$$
The alternative method is because there are six different ways to get 2 blue balls, given by:
$$\frac{4!}{2!2!} = 6$$
As the probability for obtaining two blue balls is always $$\frac{1}{15}$$ whatever combination you pick.
Therefore, the answer is:
$$6\times\frac{1}{15} = \frac{2}{5}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to reason about the problem.

Drawing 4 balls and leaving 2 in the urn is the same as choosing 2 balls to leave in the urn.

The probability that we are looking for is then the probability that neither of the 2 balls drawn is blue so the probability is:

4/6 * 3/5 = 2/6

The 4/6 is the probability of drawing the first ball that is not blue. The 3/5 is the probability of, once the first ball not blue has been drawn, another non blue ball is drawn. These two drawn balls are the ones left in the urn.

Answer (score 0):

No $2/5$ is right. See $2$ balls are fixed to come out. Thats assumption. So our favourable cases become selecting two other balls from remaining four as two blue balls should surely come out for favourable cases . thus answer $2/5$ is correct.